# exclude year when sorting by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I have a query regarding sorting by date, I can easily sort the data I have based on a field by adding

```
.order('search_date desc')
```

Search date is the date in full - dd/mm/yyyy, but I do not want to add the year to this, I only want to order by DD/MM.

Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Comment: Please specify which database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more a sql solution than a rails solution :

If you are using mysql :

```
.order("DATE_FORMAT(search_date, '%d%m')")
```

will sort by day and month

Comment: you can do something analogous in rails by passing a block into the sort method on Array, but honestly if you do it in SQL it's going to be faster anyway.

Comment: that was helpful, ended up doing .order("DATE_FORMAT(search_date, CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-%m-%d')) asc")